# Published in Azure web app appears a server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have a Web App created in Visual Studio and yesterday I deployed it to Azure App Service. 
Everything went well and now the application runs in the cloud, however when I am trying to run the next page of my app (which requires data connection) it appears the following error:

**error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation**
[image]

Here is the code from the **web.config** file which describes the connection strings:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RegistrationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EHR.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="EHREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelVac.csdl|res://*/ModelVac.ssdl|res://*/ModelVac.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EHR.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

And here is a sample from my inside code, as a sample of how i have done the connection to the sql server:

```
 try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string pa_gy = "SELECT Gender FROM P_identity WHERE (([P_Id] = @id)) ";
            SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(pa_gy, conn);
            com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id1.ToString());
            string gyn = Convert.ToString(com1.ExecuteScalar());


            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error :" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

And here are the properties of my data connection in Visual Studio (I created it there and not in SQL Server Management Studio:
[image]

How this can be solved please? I think it's something really stupid but i've got totally stuck.
(If there is something else that would be helpful for the solution, please tell me to post it)

Comment: Have you setup the database somewhere other than your local machine so the WebApp can connect to it? Your connection string shows a local db instance.

Comment: @MaviDomates I tried to change the settings through Visual Studio > Server Explorer > Modify Connection (of my data connection) and change it from Microsoft SQL Server Database file to  Microsoft SQL Server and nothing has been changed. What else should I try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDB cannot be used when the apps are deployed as azure web apps or webroles. You must create the db as a sql azure database or have it as sql db on  windows VM ( IaaS). The simpler option is the to create a sql azure db and move all your data there and use it.

here is a question that talks about migrating localdb to sql azure. 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cab265c5-1774-4237-9473-bff05e6686a5/how-can-we-move-data-from-a-localdb-database-to-a-sql-azure-database-?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Once you've done this, you can specify your deployment connection string within Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config, or by setting it directly in the Azure Portal under "Application Settings."

Comment: @jeffaudio Thanks to both of you, your comments really helped me!